# Google Drive API PHP - unauthorized_client

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client, service-accounts

I have problem using Service Account to authenticate:

```
    putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='/path/to/google.json');
    $client = new \Google_Client();
    $client->addScope(\Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);
    $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setSubject('xxx@xxx.com');
```

But it display error like this:

```
{
"error": "unauthorized_client",
"error_description": "Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method."
}
```

When I removed

```
 $client->setSubject('xxx@xxx.com');
```

It works(I have access), but there is other problem, I can't see any files created through application in my google drive(using UI). From what I heard it's just because I use Service Account and it's creating files on his own space where I can have access only through API. I need to have access to files from API and from google drive application too.

Also I need to have access to my google drive without login to my google account(without redirecting user to google login page).

If you could help me with this problem and show some examples I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remember that a service account is not you.  A service account is a dummy user it has its own google drive account.   There will be no files on the service acccounts google drive account until you upload them.

1. There is no web view for a service account.
2. You can share a folder on your personal google drive account with the service account like you would any other user using the email address.  Just make sure to have the serivce account update the permissions or you will have files on your drive account you dont have access to.
3. the service account can create a folder on its google drive account and share it with you. You should then be able to see it in the web view of your google drive account.
4. Storage limit of a service account is linked to the owner of the service account not the account it is uploading to.

Answer (score 0):

Service accounts is used to act on behalf a user. You can set the user to be your account. This way, the service account is acting on your behalf and you can see everything (using the UI) got created via you app.

To avoid the error you are facing, ensure that the following is done:

1. Create Service account using the instructions in the link below. Please note that step number 6 is an important step and don't ignore it.  https://support.google.com/a/answer/7378726?hl=en
2. Once a service account is created, you need to grant that account permissions using G-suite.

   - Copy the **client_id**. You can find it in the json file (service account credential file) or Using the Api Console, by going to Credentials > Manage Service Account then 'View Client ID'. Copy the **client_id** to clipboard
   - Launch the G-Suite Admin Console
   - Go to Security>Advanced Settings>Mange API client access.
   - Paste the **client_id** in the Client Name field, add the following  API scopes and click Authorize:

     https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group, 
     https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user, 
     https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly, 
     https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive

**Note**: If step 3 is not done, you will get the error you are getting

References:
https://support.google.com/a/answer/7378726?hl=en
https://github.com/sazaamout/gDrive